# Swift WKWebView can't use evaluateJavascript() and no event messages are received after cancelled navigation

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I'm building an iOS v15.0 app in Swift as a wrapper around a React based web app.

#### What I've done

To communicate between the iOS layer and the web layer I've set up a two-way communication system using Javascript event listeners and event dispatch calls.

My `WKWebView`, which contains the web app, injects a `WKUserScript` when it loads:

```
for webViewEventName in WKWebView.WebViewEvent.allCases {
                let eventName: String = webViewEventName.rawValue
                
                let eventListenerSource: String =
                    """
                    document.addEventListener("\(eventName)", (e) => {
                        const eventData = e.detail || null;
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.\(eventName).postMessage(eventData);
                    });
                """
                
                source += eventListenerSource
            }
```

I've implemented the `func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)` to handle the incoming events from the web app.

I'm dispatching Javascript events from the native layer (with corresponding event listeners in the web application) like this:

```
 let script: String = """
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("\(event.rawValue)", { detail: \(jsonDataString)}));
"""

// Evaluate the event dispatch in the WebView
self.evaluateJavaScript(script)
```

- **All delegate assignments are in place and the above implementation works great**
- **I've registered my primary domain in the Info.plist file for WKAppBoundDomains**

#### When it fails

Whenever in the web app we navigate to another domain that is not the same as the primary domain for my web app, the `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {` is invoked from the `WKNavigationDelegate` just as it should.

The problem is I need to handle certain URLs and custom schemes differently, for instance opening other local apps with custom schemes such as `another-app://` for third party authentication.

When handling such URLs I block navigation to the URL in my primary `WKWebView` with `decisionHandler(.cancel)`.

**Immediately** after calling `decisionHandler(.cancel)`:

- *No messages* are received in `func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)` any more
- `webView.evaluateJavascript(...)` starts throwing this error message:

```
Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=14 "JavaScript execution targeted a frame that is not in an app-bound domain" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=Unable to execute JavaScript in a frame that is not in an app-bound domain, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript execution targeted a frame that is not in an app-bound domain})
```

#### Demonstration

This code placed in the `webView:decidePolicyFor navigationAction:decisionHandler:`:

```
                // Executing javascript in WebView
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.location.href;") { result, error in
                    print(result, error)
                }
                
                // Cancelling navigation to the external URL
                print("Cancelling navigation")
                decisionHandler(.cancel) <-- This seems to put the WebView in a weird state
                
                // Executing javascript in WebView, **just as before**
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.location.href;") { result, error in
                    print(#line, result, error)
                }
```

Yields this result:

```
> Optional("http://my-url.com")
> Cancelling navigation
> Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=14 "JavaScript execution targeted a frame that is not in an app-bound domain" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=Unable to execute JavaScript in a frame that is not in an app-bound domain, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript execution targeted a frame that is not in an app-bound domain})
```

#### Note

- The web app continues to function normally, except for receiving and sending events from the `WKWebView`